# SQL Server Linked Server query to Oracle will not work when rdp onto the sql server but will work when connecting from laptop

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

We have an offsite server A hosting an Oracle database, and an on-site SQL Server B.

We have a linked server set up on B pointing at A.

If I connect from my laptop to SQL Server B and run a query against the linked server, the query will succeed.

If I remote desktop onto SQL Server B and run the same query I get the following error:

> RA-12638: Credential retrieval failed

The query works from every machine I have tried it on apart from Server B where the SQL Server is hosted, what might be causing this issue?

Comment: how is the linked server configured? e.g. how is it configured to authenticate with the oracle database?

Comment: provider: oracle provider for oledb; data source: ip address:port\service name; security: remote login and password specified; server options: all default

Comment: Possibly http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12638_credential_retrieval_failed.htm would help you?

Comment: thanks I'll take a look, its also worth pointing out we have the same issue when we try and test a connect using oracle net manager which is also installed on the sql server B

Comment: @ADyson Thank you - my answer was found in this article

Answer (score 2):

This was resolved by updating sqlnet.ora, changing authentication from NTS to NONE.

Comment: and it needed a sql service restart to take effect on the linked server